# Sorting / Ranking | IF in Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a proc that will return contact details for multiple people depending on account type.

I am using an `if` and `unions` to get the data, however I want to also order my query in proc but I am not sure of the best method.

Here is my Query:

```
    SELECT Name, Type, RecipientId FROM (
IF(@EntityType = 'Tenant')
BEGIN


SELECT
    c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
    'Tenant' AS [Type],
    tc.TenantId AS [RecipientId],
    1 AS DisplayOrder
FROM
    Tenant.Account tc
WHERE
    tc.AccountId = @EntityId

UNION

SELECT
    c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
    tc.Relationship AS [Type],
    tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
    2 AS DisplayOrder
FROM
    Tenant.Contacts tc
JOIN
    General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
WHERE
    tc.ContactId = @EntityId
END

IF(@EntityType = 'Landlord')
BEGIN


SELECT
    c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
    'Landlord' AS [Type],
    tc.LandlordId AS [RecipientId],
    2 AS DisplayOrder
FROM
    Landlords.Account tc
WHERE
    tc.LandlordId = @EntityId

UNION

SELECT
    c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
    tc.Relationship AS [Type],
    tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
    1 AS DisplayOrder
FROM
    Landlords.Contacts tc
JOIN
    General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
WHERE
    tc.ContactId = @EntityId
END) a 

 ORDER BY a.DisplayOrder
```

This is causing an error using the IF in the subquery, so any suggestions are welcome as this is a very long query in which the need to order the display from the proc has only just become a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `SORT` the Result set, inside the `IF` statement.

Try like this:

```
IF(@EntityType = 'AccountType1')
BEGIN
    SELECT Name, Type, RecipientId 
    FROM (      
            SELECT
                c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
                tc.Relationship AS [Type],
                tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
                1 AS DisplayOrder
            FROM
                Temp.Contacts tc
            JOIN
                General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
            WHERE
                tc.ContactId = @EntityId

            UNION

            SELECT
                c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
                tc.Relationship AS [Type],
                tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
                2 AS DisplayOrder
            FROM
                All.Contacts tc
            JOIN
                General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
            WHERE
                tc.ContactId = @EntityId
    )A
    ORDER BY A.DisplayOrder
END

IF(@EntityType = 'AccountType2')
BEGIN
    SELECT Name, Type, RecipientId 
    FROM (      
        SELECT
            c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
            tc.Relationship AS [Type],
            tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
            2 AS DisplayOrder
        FROM
            Temp.Contacts tc
        JOIN
            General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
        WHERE
            tc.ContactId = @EntityId

        UNION

        SELECT
            c.Title + ' ' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
            tc.Relationship AS [Type],
            tc.ContactId AS [RecipientId],
            1 AS DisplayOrder
        FROM
            All.Contacts tc
        JOIN
            General.Contact c ON tc.ContactId = c.ContactId
        WHERE
            tc.ContactId = @EntityId
    )A
    ORDER BY A.DisplayOrder
END
```

Comment: Perfect -  Thanks. Big deployment yesterday so I am frazzled. Thanks!

Comment: The pragmatic approach, +1 from my side... I'd prefer dynamic SQL or a `VIEW / iTVF` for each case though...

Answer (score 1):

If I got this correctly both queries are the same, the sole difference is the `DisplayOrder`.

Just use one single `SELECT` and replace your `1 AS DisplayOrder` with

```
CASE WHEN @EntityType = 'AccountType1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS DisplayOrder
```

And in the second occurance you take it the otherway

```
CASE WHEN @EntityType = 'AccountType1' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS DisplayOrder
```

No need for any `IF` in this case...

### Edit and update...

Had to correct a typo...

If you have more than these two types you can use the other `CASE` syntax

```
CASE @EntityType WHEN 'a' THEN 1
                 WHEN 'b' THEN 2
                 ... add more ...
                 ELSE 99 END
```

Comment: Sorry, may have been my example, sorry. These are totally different entities that rely on different tables, for example, Tenant, Landlord, Property Manager, Tenant Contact, Landlord Contact, and each of the queries get different amounts and different entities back in return.

Comment: @Dan We cannot know this... Please set up a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide DDL and DML to set up minimal but complete sample data to reproduce your issue. And please provide the expected output.

Comment: Updated my original query.

Comment: @Dan, Just as simple... Use `@EntityType AS [Type]` instead of `'Landlord' AS [Type]`.

Comment: @Dan, just saw your last update. You need to use an object name (part of it, the schema) differently (`Tenant.Account`). You can go with DineshDB, create the query dynamically or use one view for each `EntityType` and use `UNION ALL` together with a repelling WHERE clause...